# Hit By or With a plastic Bottle

Tags: prepositions

> Andrew was performing on the stage when suddenly an angry fan **hit** him
>   **with** a stone for not playing his favorite track.

vs

> Andrew was performing on the stage when suddenly an angry fan **hit** him
>   **by** a stone for not playing his favorite track.

---

> He was **hit** **by** plastic bottles too.

vs

> He was **hit** **with** plastic bottles too.

Which preposition follows **hit**?

Comment: _A fan hit him by a stone_ is ungrammatical. You can't use _by_ in an active sense like this. Even _he was hit by a stone_ is ambiguous. It could be that the stone came to life, picked up a stick and hit him with the stick!

Comment: When I read the second example (hit him by a stone) I first assumed that there happened to be a bunch of stones on the stage (as props) and the fan hit him (with his fist) near one of them.

Comment: @SethRobertson Which nicely points out that the sentence is not ungrammatical. The meaning of the grammatical interpretation is just such that people presume it unlikely and choose the meaning which makes the sentence ungrammatical. The fact this can happen has always confused me even though I understand it logically.

Comment: @OscarBravo As Seth points out the sentence is grammatical just not if you want to say what you expect the speaker to want to say.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Traditionally, **by** indicated an agent, the doer of the action, and **with** indicated the instrument used by the agent.

However, there's a large grey area between the two.

If a fan hit Andrew with a stone, the implication is that the fan was holding the stone and using it as a weapon.

If Andrew was hit by a stone, the implication is that the fan threw the stone at Andrew or, in other circumstances, that the stone was dislodged and fell on Andrew.

The same applies to plastic bottles. One can be struck with a plastic bottle or by a plastic bottle.

When it comes to missiles, it's more complicated. People are struck by bullets and arrows, even though these are instruments rather than agents. You can also be struck by a (flying) knife although you are more likely to be stabbed with one.

We also talk about people being hit by a bus and killed by falling trees. You might be killed with a tree, but only if somebody was using the tree to kill you, which is a bit improbable although not impossible.

So the choice of preposition depends on the context and on idiomatic use.

http://www.grammaring.com/the-agent-with-the-passive-voice
https://teddymedinal.blogspot.com/2015/01/prepositions-of-agent-or-instrument.html

Comment: so here's what I used to think- Andrew was hit by a truck. ( truck is the object that hit andrew). Richard hit Andrew with his truck ( richard, the doer, hit andrew, with his truck). If some object does something on a person or another object, we use BY and if we have mentioned the subject that makes it do something, we use With. Is this interpretation wrong/incorrect ?

Comment: @SubratBavarianBastola Your interpretation would hold true in some circumstances but not in all.

Comment: This is correct: both of your water bottle sentences work, but they mean different things (the first suggests angry fans threw water bottles at him; the second that the angry fans rushed the stage and used their water bottles like clubs to beat him). But note your second stone sentence doesn't work; you can't *hit someone **by** something* (unless you mean that you hit someone while standing next to the thing). If you want to keep the angry fan in the sentence, you'd have to reword it and probably include the verb *throw* somehow, e.g. "suddenly he was hit by a stone thrown by an angry fan."

Answer (score 7):

**with** is your preposition

According to Cambridge Dictionary

**[with](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/with)** [METHOD]

> using **something**
>
> *He was shot at close range **with** a pistol.*
>
> *She wiped her lipstick off **with** a tissue.*
>
> *Join the two pieces together **with** glue.*
>
> *Please handle this package **with** care.*

**[by](http://used%20to%20show%20the%20person%20or%20thing%20that%20does%20something)** [AGENT]

> used to show **the person or thing** that does something

**by** [METHOD]

> used to show **how** something is done

Notice that the prepositions listed above answer these questions respectively: what?, who?, how?.

For example you can use **by** [AGENT] in

> He was hit by plastic bottles too.

if we are talking about a movie in which a group of evil angry plastic bottles gain conscience and movility and rebel against humanity. But this situation rarely happens in real life. ;-)

**IMPORTANT EDIT**: As pointed by Ronald Sole, Chris Petheram and Shadur, you can actually be **hit by** non-conscious plastic bottles, for example if someone throws it to your head. Ronald has compiled some good examples in his answer.

Comment: You beat me by *time!* I was writing an answer almost similar to this! Worth to note that irrespective of logic shown here, we find both types of examples on COCA and Ngram! Anyway, +1

Comment: @MaulikV You were going to use my Evil Bottles take the World script too? ;-P What is COCA? I don't know that acronym.

Comment: Although you don't actually need conscious motive to use 'by'. See "During the Coke factory explosion, I was hit by plastic bottles"

Comment: @ChrisPetheram You are right [Editing]

Comment: @Ronald Sole , so here's what I used to think-     Andrew was hit by a truck. ( truck is the object that hit andrew).               Richard hit Andrew with his truck (  richard, the doer, hit andrew, with his truck). If some object does something on a person or another object, we use BY and if we have mentioned the subject that makes it do something, we use With.    Is this interpretation wrong/incorrect?

Comment: @SubratBavarianBastola I think that it's correct but Ronald's answer is above mine ;-P

Answer (score 2):

> He was hit by plastic bottles too.

This implies it was an accident, or that no one could be identified as the agent. So the bottles take on a connotation of agency to suggest no one is responsible, or that "He" was not an intended target. We say, "He was hit by a car," because it's usually accidental.

> He was hit with plastic bottles too.

Here is a strong indication that another person is in the context, and was identified in some way, or that it was intentional by someone.